# Volume limited by two planes (solution check)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the volume limited by $x,y,z>0$ and the planes $y+z=1$ and $x+2y=1$. This is what I did

$$ V= \int_{x=0}^1 \int _{y=0}^{(1-x)/2}\int_{z=0}^{1-y} 1 \ \  dzdydx $$
I am not interested in the result, I just want to know if I put the limits of the integrals correct. Thanks.

Comment: Oh , That looks Correct !!!

Comment: Thank you Prem!